# Android Service possible reuse?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service, android-service

i am doing a project where 2 people connect via wifi-hotspot (One as the hotspot, the other one connects to it by wifi) and they can exchange messages (i will make files later).

I created the socket connection using two services (with two threads inside, one to send info, another one to read info), one for the server and another one for the client. The communication should be bidirectional and can be started by any of them and here is where i have a problem.

Basically in the beggining, i start the service and start the thread to receive ( i set an action and check it on the method onStartCommand, to know which thread to create). Then a person has a button, that if they press it, they can send a message. If a person sends a message, i will start the service again (and set the action to SEND, so that i can start the thread to send the message).

The problem is that if i start the service again (to send), i will get the exception of the socket being already in use (already tried doing the setReuseAddress(true) and it is not working). I get a similar problem for the streams, they will not be "related" (The outputstream from one side is not the correspondent one to the inputstream from the other side - they exchange a header every time they are created).

**How do you guys think i could solve this?** I could put the streams and the socket's as static, and check if they are already created, but that doesn't seem too consistent. If you guys need, i can post the code, but it will be kind of long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply check if socket is using or not and close it

```
private boolean isPortInUse(String host, int port) {
  // Assume no connection is possible.
  boolean result = false;

  try {
    (new Socket(host, port)).close();
    result = true;
  }
  catch(SocketException e) {
    // Could not connect.
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i can not close that socket, because i still want to "listen" to something that is being sent to me. Like i said, it is a bidirectional communication and any of the envolved parts can start sending data.

Comment: create socket in OnCreate() and fetch them in OnstartCommand() so whenever the service restart then  OnstartCommand() calls and and you can reuse the socket

Comment: That is exactly what i did. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I did it, but since this is a new account, it still doesn't show the votes that i make